# Iterative Lag with calculation result from previous row: conditional cumulative product and sum

Tags: r, dplyr, spss

## The actual question

Given the data following data:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(v1 = 1:6, cond = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))

## # A tibble: 6 × 2
##      v1  cond
##   <int> <dbl>
## 1     1     1
## 2     2     0
## 3     3     1
## 4     4     1
## 5     5     0
## 6     6     1
```

I want to calculate a mixture of cumulative sum and cumulative product.
If *cond = 1* calcutate the *sum* of current v1 and the results of the
preceding calculations. If *cond = 0* calculate the *product* of current
v1 and the results of the preceeding calcultions.

The desired result should look like this:

```
## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##      v1  cond cum_prodsum
##   <int> <dbl>       <int>
## 1     1     1           1
## 2     2     0           2
## 3     3     1           5
## 4     4     1           9
## 5     5     0          45
## 6     6     1          51
```

In SPSS this is the code I would use:

```
COMPUTE cum_prodsum = 0.
IF($casenum = 1 & cond = 1) cum_prodsum = v1.
IF($casenum > 1 & cond = 0) cum_prodsum = lag(cum_prodsum) * v1
IF($casenum > 1 & cond = 1) cum_prodsum = lag(cum_prodsum) + v1.
```

But how can this be done in R?

*Sounds like a silly task that noone never ever would need to do? Yeah,
it probably is. But think of it as a simple example for a whole group of
problems where the calculation of the current row depends on the
calculation results of the preceding rows.*

## Some information for (former) SPSS users working with R (not part of the question)

When I used to work with *SPSS* I often used a combination of the `IF`
and `LAG` command in order to do some common tasks, such as slicing the
data and keeping only the first row of each group. When I started
working with R, I quickly learned, that for those common task, R usually
comes with some handy functions, so that there is no need to program own
routines with the lag function. And even for not so common task, a
little research often leads to solution without iterating through the
data.

In the end the situations where I think “Well, I know how to do it in
SPSS with the LAG command. But how could I do it in R?” are very very
rare. The *dplyr* package from R comes with a `lag` function but it
works different, so that the naive approach substituting SPSS-LAG by the
R-lag would not work.

### Difference between LAG from SPSS and dplyr:lag from R

Let’ say you have the following data with just one column:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(v1 = 1:6)

## # A tibble: 6 × 1
##      v1
##   <int>
## 1     1
## 2     2
## 3     3
## 4     4
## 5     5
## 6     6
```

When computing a new a variable in SPSS with lag, SPSS processes cases
sequentially from top to bottom. The results from the calculation of the
preceding rows can be used for computing the current row.

```
COMPUTE lagsum_spss = v1.
IF ($casenum > 1) lagsum_spss = lagsum_spss + LAG(lagsum_spss).
```

Which results in:

```
## # A tibble: 6 × 2
##      v1 lagsum_spss
##   <int>       <int>
## 1     1           1
## 2     2           3
## 3     3           6
## 4     4          10
## 5     5          15
## 6     6          21
```

The `dplyr::lag` function on the other hand, is a vectorised function,
which applies the calculations to all elements in a vector
simultaneously. So when I try mimicking the SPSS behavior in R with the
`mutate` and `lag` functions I get a different result:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(lagsum_r = v1,
         lagsum_r = lagsum_r + lag(lagsum_r, default = 0))

## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##      v1 lagsum_spss lagsum_r
##   <int>       <int>    <dbl>
## 1     1           1        1
## 2     2           3        3
## 3     3           6        5
## 4     4          10        7
## 5     5          15        9
## 6     6          21       11
```

The fourth row, for example is calculates as this:
`lagsum_spss[4] = 4 + 6` and `lagsum_r[4] = 4 + 3`.

So how can we reproduce this calculation in R? Well in this case it is
quite simple:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(v1))

## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##      v1 lagsum_spss cumsum
##   <int>       <int>  <int>
## 1     1           1      1
## 2     2           3      3
## 3     3           6      6
## 4     4          10     10
## 5     5          15     15
## 6     6          21     21
```

See, no need for lag, this time.

OK OK, but what if I want to sum only values from cases that meet a
certain condition, a **conditional cumsum** if you say so?

Example data set:

```
df <- tibble(v1 = 1:6, cond = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
df

## # A tibble: 6 × 2
##      v1  cond
##   <int> <dbl>
## 1     1     1
## 2     2     0
## 3     3     1
## 4     4     1
## 5     5     0
## 6     6     1
```

The SPSS code would look like this:

```
COMPUTE cond_cumsum = 0.
IF($casenum = 1 & cond = 1) cond_cumsum = v1.
IF($casenum > 1 & cond = 0) cond_cumsum = lag(cond_cumsum).
IF($casenum > 1 & cond = 1) cond_cumsum = lag(cond_cumsum) + v1.
```

So how this can be done in R? Well the solution is also pretty easy:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cond_cumsum = cumsum(v1 * cond))

## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##      v1  cond cond_cumsum
##   <int> <dbl>       <dbl>
## 1     1     1           1
## 2     2     0           1
## 3     3     1           4
## 4     4     1           8
## 5     5     0           8
## 6     6     1          14
```

For a task, where I think it is unavoidable to to iterate through the
data rows, see the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what we want to do is basicly this: Start with the two first elements
of a vector as input, do stuff with it, use that outcome as the first
input and the next vector element as the second input, do the same stuff
again, use that outcome as new first input … and so on. If you heard
about the `Reduce` (base R) or `reduce` and `accumulate` (purrr)
functions, this may sound familiar.

This is an illustration from the [purrr Cheat Sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/purrr.pdf) of how the accumulate
function works:

[image]

Lets first think about the function that we want to apply:

- first we want to check if `cond` is 0 or 1
- if `cond` is 1 then *sum* `v1` from the current row with the outcome from
  the preceeding step.
- if not, then *multiply* `v1` from the current row with the outcome from
  the preceeding step.

So we program this function in R:

```
function(last_result, i){ # i stands for the row index.
  if(condition[i]) last_result + v1[i]
  else last_result * v1[i]
}
```

Now lets think about the first row, since we have no “last_result”
which we could throw into that function. Following the idea of a
cumulative sum, and a cumulative product. The value should be
`cumsum(v1[1])` if `cond[1]` is 1 or `prodsum(v1[1])` if not. In both cases
these functions will return `v1[1]`. So this is our initial value for
the first row.

OK now, lets put this together for the accumulate function from the
purrr package:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    cum_prodsum = accumulate(
      .x = row_number()[-1], # apply the funtion on all rows, except the first one.
      .init = v1[1],         # initial value for the first row.
      .f = function(last_result, i) {
        if (cond[i]) last_result + v1[i]
        else last_result * v1[i]
      }
    ))

## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##      v1  cond cum_prodsum
##   <int> <dbl>       <int>
## 1     1     1           1
## 2     2     0           2
## 3     3     1           5
## 4     4     1           9
## 5     5     0          45
## 6     6     1          51
```

And this is it. For similar type of problems where the calculation of a
value depends on the calculations of the preceeding values, just adjust
the function within the accumulate command to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this - very useful for all (former) SPSSers fooling around with R

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  tibble(v1 = as.numeric(1:6), v2 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))

df %>%
  mutate(output = case_when(v2 == 1 ~ cumsum(v1),
                         v2 == 0 ~ cumprod(v1)))
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the 'output' variable is not the desired result. Compare it with cum_prodsum column in the question.